# How can I render xml using Koa.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, koa, koa-router

It seems like html breaks if I just render xml text using `ctx.body` because everything goes into body element not as raw xml. I read all the documentation but couldn't find proper response function for rendering xml.

This is my code and how it looks like on browser!

```
router.get('/:tag', async (ctx, next) => 
    (ctx.body = await rssGenerator(ctx.params.tag)))
```

[image]

Comment: Try setting a correct Content-Type header

Comment: Try adding something like `ctx.type = 'text/xml'`